# Libsvm with multi labels

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I gave a matrix with labels as 1,2,3 to libsvm and got 70% accuracy... I was wondering if it is correct or not ?

Does anyone know if libsvm handles multi class by itself and if it does is it one v/s all ? If not what exactly is this 70% accuracy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`official documentation`](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) for LibSVM states

> LIBSVM implements the “one-against-one” approach (Knerr et al., 1990) for multi-
>   class classification. If k is the number of classes, then k(k − 1)/2 classifiers are
>   constructed and each one trains data from two classes.

The document goes on to say that classification is essentially the outcome of a voting procedure. Each of the classifiers votes on each data point and it is assigned to whichever class has the most votes for it. For accuracy, I presume these labels would be matched against the known class labels and the percentage reported is the percentage of label agreement.